# Wrapping is not happen in floated element's text because of no width set

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive mobile web page using twitter-bootstrap.css and angularjs.

I am trying to accommodate one image and text side by side in a row using float concepts.see screenshots below.

I give width to the image and i didn't give width to the text, as i want the text to take the remaining width left out by the image,

But it is not happening, text comes to the next line instead of wrapping into the available width left out by the image,when the text is more than the width.

**Screen shot #1**

When text contains within the width left out by the image, when the text content's width is less than available width left out by the image.

[image: http://i38.tinypic.com/wuqnuq.png]

[(Link to the full image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2htF8.png)

**Screen shot #2**

When text comes to new line instead of wrapping within the width left out by the image, when the text content's width is more than available width left out by the image

[image: http://i38.tinypic.com/vg04k8.png]

[(Link to the full image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIjvJ.png)

**Screen shot #3**

As i needed, when text comes wraps within the width left out by the image, when the text content's width is more than available width left out by the image. But width is set for text.

[image: http://i34.tinypic.com/33lfrd1.png]

[(Link to the full image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE9p4.png)

My Code is

```
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My HTML File</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
        <style>
            .float-left {float:left !important;}
            .clearIt {clear:both !important;}
            .marRight5{margin-right:5px}
            .BgImg{background: url(images/img.png) no-repeat;height:25px;width:25px}
        </style>

        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="BgImg float-left marRight5"></div>
            <div class=" float-left">This is test content This is test content This is test content This is test content This is test content</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the float off your text div. Floated elements do not wrap around other floats, they float around them as a block, wrapping to a new line if necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jP6yd/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="BgImg float-left marRight5"></div>
    <div>This is test content This is test content This is test content This is test content This is test content</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the text comes to new line after the image height is over.

Comment: Your fiddle still has a float on the text. I assume since you've accepted my answer that you've already realized this.

Comment: sorry i forget to save my fiddle, now i have saved my fiddle as u mentioned by removing float-left.